# Left join with where clause for right table (Must return NULL from right) - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, null, left-join, where-clause

I have 2 tables ID and Comm. The tables are as follows

```
 
ID                          
AppID   Name
1       James
2       John
.
.
100     Jeff

Comm
AppID  Comment
1      abc
1      def
1      pqr
2      abc
2      def
2      pqr
3      def
```

I want all appID from ID (First table) and from Comm(Second table) I want only those comment which are equal to **abc**, rest others should be NULL.

I am using following query, not sure how do I filter comment **abc** and Null

```
select id.appid,comm.comment
from id left join comm on
id.appid=comm.appid
where comm.comment = 'abc'
```

I know I have the logic wrong, trying to figure out where should I change.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `WHERE` to `AND`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select id.appid,comm.comment
from id 
left join comm 
    on id.appid=comm.appid
    and comm.comment = 'abc'
```

Comment: the best and the fastest way. thanks bro.

Comment: For me its selecting all the data not selecting based on the condition on the right table.

Comment: @AmanDeep , as stated by the OP: "I want all appID from ID (First table) and from Comm(Second table) I want only those comment which are equal to abc, rest others should be NULL." Can you elaborate on what you believe is the problem with the query in the answer?

Comment: consider I have table_users and *table_position*, table_position can have multiple records associated with one user with a foreign key in *table_position* which is *created_by_id*.
i only want to select the records from table_user where position_id = 2

Comment: Are you asking a new question in a comment? You should create a new question preferably with create table statements and insert statements for sample data. You can also use https://dbfiddle.uk/ to setup the scenario and include the link

Answer (score 1):

Use two left join, and then union them.

```
select id.appid,comm.comment 
from id left join comm 
on id.appid=comm.appid 
where comm.comment = 'abc'
union
select comm.appid,comm.comment 
from comm  left join id
on idcomm.appid=id.appid
where comm.comment = 'abc'
```